# how to execute HTTP POST request in android without using Json

Tags: android, mysql

I have made this code where i am to send the data to a MYSQL Database using POST request. I have made the following code using POST request. So,just wanted to ask first IF THIS CODE WOULD RUN WELL OR NOT

And i would b very grateful to that person if someone could just tell m what specifically is the setRequestProperty("Key","Value") method used for and what is meant by this KEY and VALUE in it.

I have provided Internet permissions in the manifest file too.

Please reply as soon as possible.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.221.105/hanish/datainsert.php");
        HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        client.setRequestMethod("POST");
        client.setRequestProperty(“id”,”l”);
        client.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        writeStream(outputPost);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void writeStream(OutputStream outputPost) throws IOException {
    String v= l;
    outputPost.write(v.getBytes());
    outputPost.flush();
}
```

Comment: `IF THIS CODE WOULD RUN WELL OR NOT`. Well try it out i would say. And dont shout.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should run async task. However, I'd recommend using [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library. It handles async requests for you.

To use this library you should add maven dependency using Gradle buildscript in format:

```
   dependencies {
     compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
   }
```

Then, import the http package:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.*;
```

And then write following code:

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
requestParams.add("id", "1");
asyncHttpClient.post("http://192.168.221.105/hanish/datainsert.php", requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        String response = new String(responseBody); // this is your response string
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        // Here you write code if there's error
    }
});
```

I hope this will help.